# Change Link Styling Based on Current Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I have a single HTML page with a fixed position top level navigation menu with links that lead to different sections. Is there a way to change the color of my links when a user reaches the corresponding section (either by clicking the link itself or scrolling down to the section)?

This is what my HTML looks like, basically:

```
<div id="topNav">
     <ul>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#web_design">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>

<div id="home">
     <img src="images/dog.jpg" class="bg" />
</div>
<div id="web_design">
     <img class="titleImage" src="images/web_design.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="contact">
     <img class="titleImage" src="images/contact.jpg" />
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
#topNav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
}
```

I'd like to use a class "selected" for my list items and probably apply it to whichever link corresponds to the user's current section, and do something like:

```
#topNav li.selected a {
    color: #cbcacc;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/TxSt2/ . It will take a little more (that I'll try and add) to have the scroll effect

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an item called **scrollspy**. There are some free stuffs all the web:

- [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/) is an lightweight example
- Some jQuery scrollspy plugin in [jQuery plugin registry](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/scrollspy/)
- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) scrollspy javascript plugin

You can also google with the keyword **scrollspy** for more stuffs.

This is the code from the above fillde:

JS

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="topNav">
     <ul>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#web_design">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="home">
     <img src="images/dog.jpg" class="bg" />
</div>
<div id="web_design">
     <img class="titleImage" src="images/web_design.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="contact">
     <img class="titleImage" src="images/contact.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#topNav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
}

div.spacer {
    height: 80px;
}

#topNav li.selected a {
    color: #cbcacc;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS3 has an interesting selector **:target**, you can style your links based on the targets , you can do something like this

:target{color:#ff0000;}

Try google for css3 target selector